# Calling script from shell script - getting command not found

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to work through this.

```
> script to execute in cron (util.sh)
#!/bin/sh
HOST='ahostname'
PORT='3306'
USER='auser'
PASS='apassword'
DB='adatabase'
. /mnt/stor/backups/backup.sh
```

(I also tried source /mnt/stor/backups/backup.sh)

```
 > script to execute (backup.sh)
```

When backup.sh is called (it does get called) it appears to simply be parsed and not executed. So no matter what I put in it I get messages like:

```
/mnt/stor/backups/backup.sh: line 8: date: command not found
/mnt/stor/backups/backup.sh: line 8: mysqldump: command not found
/mnt/stor/backups/backup.sh: line 8: tar: command not found
/mnt/stor/backups/backup.sh: line 8: rm: command not found
```

The idea is to have a domain localized file, execute it with variables, and call a master script that uses the variable to do the dirty work. Because of limitations with one of my hosts and multiple domains this is the best method.

Comment: Most likely the sub-shell has a much different PATH than the parent shell. Try adding absolute paths to the commands, e.g. `/bin/rm`, `/bin/tar`, etc...

Comment: Looks like the `PATH` isn't properly set for cron's commands. If that's the case, using absolute pathnames to your commands (date, tar, etc.) or setting a `PATH` in backup.sh might help.

Comment: Looks even like something is actively zapping or sabotaging your `PATH` - basic commands like `rm` should certainly be available even with a limited `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script with the Problem seems to be `/mnt/stor/backups/backup.sh`. Try setting the PATH to include all the usual directories with binaries, so the script can find its tools. Or, even better, change `/mnt/stor/backups/backup.sh` and use absolute paths in the commands like `/bin/rm` instead of just `'rm'`.

Answer (score 1):

When running from cron, you can't rely on any variables that are normally in your login shell's profile (e.g.: PATH, CLASSPATH, etc). You have to set explicitly what you need. In your case, i'm guessing that it's the lack of a PATH variable that's causing your troubles.

It's also good practice to put full paths to the programs you're executing from an unattended script, just to make sure you really are going to run that specific command, i.e., don't rely on the path.

So instead of

```
date
```

for example, use

```
/bin/date
```

etc.